# SwiftUI Set Image Boundary

Tags: swift, swiftui

i want to set my right image frame boundaries like the left one without moving image or text. How can I do that. I tried a couple way but I couldn't find the solution.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Im trying to set my ımage right  boundary as you can see in tabbar profile picture. İ want to make boundary like left one I mean closer to picture.

Comment: So are you trying to create a tab bar with equally-spaced images (above)?

Comment: Yes exactly , also want to make sure ımages frame  boundaries do not intersect with other.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the built-in `TabView`. It provides all the functionality for you, and already made with accessibility in mind.

Here is an example (you can change it for your text and images):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("Tab Content 1")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("1", systemImage: "1.square")
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            Text("Tab Content 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("2", systemImage: "2.square")
                }
                .tag(2)
            
            Text("Tab Content 3")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("3", systemImage: "3.square")
                }
                .tag(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: TabView showing 3 separate sections as an example]

---

Custom version (**highly unrecommended**):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Main Content")
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        //
                    } label: {
                        Label("1", systemImage: "1.square")
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        //
                    } label: {
                        Label("2", systemImage: "2.square")
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        //
                    } label: {
                        Label("3", systemImage: "3.square")
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }.frame(height: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know tabview but the problem with tabview is its not allow to create more than 5 tabbar . thats why I created custom tabbar . because I have to show 6 tabbar.But apple not reccomend and let you create more than 5 with tabview.

Comment: @Begbie If that's the limit, then stick with the limit. 6 tabs could be a usability nightmare. Try change what your tabs are for. I can't read the language in your original image, but something like "Home", "Profile", "Settings" sort of thing would be the best way. For example in profile you may have different options, which don't have to be their own tab. Do not remake a tab view it will be unnecessary pain and an issue for the user.

Comment: I know . im agree with you , its not a good UX for user also but the problem is the company Im working for already made this design and they want me to do this way . So basically I dont have a choice :(

Comment: @Begbie As the developer, you should question why the designer chose this - they may not know the limits of the default `TabView`. They will want a good app - and you want to make the good app too. Just question the designer something like stating that the app won't fit with Apple's `Human Interface Guidelines`. Please also link them to [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/) and to read the "Avoid having too many tabs" section. There is a high chance Apple could also reject the app for this, so this should be their priority.

Comment: @Begbie Adjusting the design during the development process will always happen in any company - and making sure this is right is essential so it won't get rejected. It's fine the designer may not have known the capabilities, but just send them the link I sent above so they can have a read through and be more careful next time.

Comment: I told them many times , and they already know its not fit with Apple's Human Interfaces but even that they still want me to do this way.No other choice unfortunately.

Comment: @Begbie I don't know what to say - weird for a company to be willing to spend more money on development time for a worse product which may not even be accepted. Ok, in that case, I will add a short answer to the bottom of mine in a minute.

Comment: @Begbie Added it. I have to go now so can't reply until later.